# How to dynamically show/hide some rows in mat-table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have used a mat-table component in my Angular app, where results of some sport events are displayed. Normally, I want to show only three best results and then, when the user clicks the "ellipsis button" (like on the related pic) - the table should expand and show rest, hidden rows. I have problems with using *ngIf statement in the  markup, because I'm not allowed to have more than one attribute with * prefix. How to do it in a different way? Thanks in advance.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="qualifyingResults" class="exo-2">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>POS</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let result">{{ result.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="driver">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="center-header">DRIVER</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let result" class="text-center font-weight-bold">{{ result.Driver.code }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>TIME</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let result">{{ result.time }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily. In your dataSource, get only the first 3 results. Then bind the ellipsis button click event to a function where you get the rest of the data. Then update the dataSource.

Something like this:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getThreeResults.subscribe(
    data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)
  )
}

onEllipsisButtonClick() {
  this.getRestOfTheData.subscribe(
    data => this.dataSource.data = data
  )
}
```